# Driver problems for SH-S203N Samsung DVD drive

Tags: windows

My father just bought me a dvd burner Samsung SH-S202N OEM and installed it into my computer. The drive seems to be able to burn media fine. But when it comes to reading dvd's, audio cd's, it just skips. It can read them it is just skipping so badly to the point where the dvd's are unwatchable and cd's skip rather badly. I am looking for the latest firmware or driver for the Samsung SH-S202N OEM. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t find the latest firmware and driver on Samsung website? Type [driver for SH-S203N](http://www.driverwikipedia.com/) in web browser to search online, you might find the suitable driver for you. If you can’t find the right one, you can try driver update tool.